# Copying Redis dump.rdb from version 2.6 to 2.4

Tags: redis, windows-server-2008

I am currently using Redis 2.6.16 in our Linux server. Since our client needs to transfer to a Windows Server, I downloaded the Redis 2.4.6 installer from [rgl github](https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads). Now, I need to copy the dump.rdb from our Linux server to the Windows Server. But, it kept on saying that it cannot read the version from the dump.rdb file. I followed the instructions from [Redis RDB Version History](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/blob/master/docs/RDB_Version_History.textile) but still no success in making it work in my Windows Server.

Last error that I got from the logs is:

```
FATAL: Data file was created with a Redis server configured to handle more than 16 databases. Exiting
```

Do you know other installers for Windows so that I can have the same version as with my Linux server (Redis 2.6.16)? Or do you know any other way I can work around through it? Thanks!

Comment: You can download Redis for windows from : http://sourceforge.net/projects/redis/files/redis-2.6.10/

Comment: or build from source from https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis

Comment: You may not have to install the exact same version (depending on what you want oc). The message is clear, just configure your redis instance (in the .conf file) to handle more databases. Restart redis, and try again.

Comment: The original .conf file and the current .conf file both have 16 databases setup.